# Finding the longest increasing subsequence of an array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am a beginner to python and have already gone through other solutions for this problem. I was wondering if I could take another approach (this might be much slower, but I want to be able to tackle problems with a similar approach):

I noted that for a number n in our sequence with index (position in of the number in the sequence) i, if there exists another number in our sequence m with index y, such that, n > m and i > y, we can say with certainty that n is not the 1st entry of the longest increasing subsequence of our sequence.
I hope to apply this condition to our sequence to get all possible candidates for the 1st entry of LIS. From there we only consider the sequence that comes after our candidates and apply our condition again so that we get all possible second entries of the LIS.
We keep doing this, assembling all possible subsequences as we go along and at the end we choose the largest subsequence.

```
def LIS(sequence):
    
    candidates = []
    
    for i in range(0,len(sequence)):
        candidates.append(i)
    
    for i in range(0,len(sequence)):
        for y in range(0,len(sequence)):
            if sequence[i] > sequence[y] and i > y:
                candidates.remove(i)
                
                break
      
    
    return(candidates)
```

This is what the condition looks like when I write it out in code. But I am not able to wrap my head around how I can apply this condition again and again  to get the LIS

Comment: Why is this tagged `recursion`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I thought a recursive function can be used to apply this condition again and again until we arrive at the LIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct, that can be used to decide the potential candidates for the first number of our LIS. However, there is a way to simplify your `n>m and i>y` logic. It effectively states that a number can't be a candidate if it has a smaller number to the left of it. So all you have to do is keep a track of the smallest number on the left, and iterate.
For each candidate, recursively continue the process, till no valid candidates are found, and then return the LIS sequence obtained.

```
def candidates(lst, base_index, min_val):
    if base_index>=len(lst):
        return []
    if lst[base_index]>min_val:
        ans = [base_index]   #0th index will always be a candidate
        min_left = lst[base_index]
    else:
        ans = []
        min_left = int(1e8)
    for i in range(base_index+1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i]<min_left and lst[i]>min_val:
            ans.append(i)
            min_left = min(min_left, lst[i])
    return ans   # list of indexes of potential candidates 

def lis(lst, i):
    # returns LIS starting at index i
    seq = []
    ans = [i]
    candidate_list = candidates(lst, i+1, lst[i])
    for candidate in candidate_list:
        temp = lis(lst, candidate) #LIS starting at each candidate
        if len(temp)>len(seq):
            seq = temp
    ans += seq
    return ans

def lis_helper(lst):
    ans = []
    candidate_list = candidates(lst,0, -int(1e8))
    for candidate in candidate_list:
        temp = lis(lst, candidate)
        if len(temp)>len(ans):
            ans = temp
    return ans  #list of indexes that make up the LIS

lst  = [5,6,1,0,4,6,7]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
lst3 = [5,4,3,2,1]

print(lis_helper(lst))   # [2, 4, 5, 6]
print(lis_helper(lst2))  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(lis_helper(lst3))  # [0]
```

Comment: But after I get the list of candidates, I want consider the part of the sequence after each candidate and get the list of candidates for the second entry of the subsequence that corresponds to the candidate under consideration and thus assemble the entire LIS

Comment: Do you need the sequence, or the length of the LIS?

Comment: I need the sequence

Comment: In the if condition of the lis  function, why have you given the 1st and 2nd conditions? These conditions are always true right?

Comment: @RicardoRodriguez yes, forgot to remove it from there. Updated now

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def LIS(sequence):
    if(len(sequence)==0): return 0
    candidates = [[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(sequence)):
        added_ = False
        for j in range(len(candidates)):
            k = 0
            if(sequence[i]>=sequence[candidates[j][-1]]):
                candidates[j].append(i)
            else:
                for k in range(len(candidates[j])-2, -1, -1):
                    if(sequence[i]>=sequence[candidates[j][k]]):
                        candidates.append(candidates[j][:k+1]+[i])
                        k = -1 # so k=0 means no match found in the middle
                        break
                    if(k==0) and ~added_:
                        candidates.append([i])
                        added_ = True
    return sorted(candidates, key=len)[-1]
```

Few notes:

1. You need to try to fit `sequence` elements not only at the end, but also in the middle of other `candidates` - you might get better fit with that way, take for example seq: `[2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 0, 1, 6]` where you can establish 2 sequences ending with `6` i.e. you might find overlapping sequences, where the longer starts with greater number. So you need to loop over all candidates for each number of `sequence` to make sure you won't lose anything
2. I did it backwards to the theorem i.e. I'm looping through `sequence` from the start - you can try to revert it so you get it more aligned